# What is the isomorphism class of the kernel of a homomorphism of cyclic groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

> Consider the homomorphism $\phi:(\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})\to\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $(a,b)\mapsto a+b$. What is the isomorphism class of $\ker\phi$?

The elements of $\ker\phi$ consist of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a+b=3n$ for a positive integer $n\leq9$. There are $27\times 3=9\times 9=81$ elements of $\ker\phi$, since given the first coordinate, there are 3 options for the second coordinate (e.g., choosing 1 for the first coordinate of an element of $\ker\phi$, we can have 2, 5, or 8 in the second coordinate). However, I'm not sure how to find the group structure on this set, except to say that $\ker\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})$. (But in this case we have normality anyway because the groups are abelian.)

A hint would be very appreciated.

Comment: One element in the kenel is $(1,-1)$.  What is its order in $\mathbf Z/27\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/9\mathbf Z$?  Use the classification of finite abelian groups to show every subgroup of $\mathbf Z/p^a\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/p^b\mathbf Z$ is *isomorphic* to $\mathbf Z/p^i\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/p^j\mathbf Z$ where $i \leq a$ and $j \leq b$.

Comment: Could I make sure I understand the strategy you're suggesting? We use the fact that the group has the form $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p^j\mathbb{Z}$, then consider an element of the kernel of the greatest possible order to find $p^i$. Then we're left to find $p^j$ by looking at the order of $\text{ker}\phi$.

Comment: The kernel has size $81$ and the maximal possible order an element of the kernel can have is $27$.  What's the order of $(1,-1)$ in the kernel? Making all that information consistent will reveal the abstract group structure of the kernel

Comment: By the way, if you look up the classification of finite abelian groups you'll find that when $a$ is an element of maximal order in a finite abelian group $A$, there is a direct product decomposition $A \cong \langle a\rangle \times B$ for some subgroup $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u,v$ be the classes of $(1,-1)$ and $(0,3)$ in $\Bbb Z/27\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$. Their orders are respectively $27$ and $3$, and every element of $\ker\phi$ writes uniquely
$$au+cv,\quad 0\le a<27,\quad0\le c<3,$$
hence
$$\ker\phi=\langle u\rangle\oplus\langle v\rangle\simeq\Bbb Z/27\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z.$$
Edit: proof (upon request by two comments) that every element in $\ker\phi$ writes uniquely
$$au+cv,\quad 0\le a<27,\quad0\le c<3.$$ Let
$x\in[0,27),y\in[0,9)$ be integers such that $3\mid x+y$. Then, the class of $(x,y)$ in
$\Bbb Z/27\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$ writes as above iff
$$a\in[0,27),\quad c\in[0,3),\quad x\equiv a\bmod{27},\text{ and }y\equiv-a+3c\bmod9,$$
i.e. iff
$$a=x,\quad c\in[0,3),\text{ and }x+y\equiv3c\bmod9,$$
i.e. $a=x$ and $c$ is the unique integer in $[0,3)$ such that $c\equiv\frac{x+y}3\bmod3$.

Answer (score 2):

Lets call G the group. A good way of narrowing down is using a consecuense of the first theorem of isomorphism as the cardinalities are finite and the morphism is surjective, we have:

$$|\ker(\phi)|\cdot |img(\phi)| = |G|$$

Where we get $|\ker(\phi)|= 3^4$

Then if we take $a$ and $b$ module 3, you can see that if $a\equiv 0 \implies b\equiv 0$ as $a+b\equiv 0$ analogously $a\equiv 1 \implies b\equiv 2$ and $a\equiv 2 \implies b\equiv 1$ and this cover all cases and more over the cardinalities argument will prove that this are all cases.

The preivuos analisis gives the elements in the kernel $$\{(3k,3l),(3k+1,3l+2),(3k+2,3l+1)|k,l \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

And for each form is a simple count that are $3^3$ elements, and three (disjoint) forms, having $3^4$ elements ie all the elements in the kernel.

Finally by the way we find the elements in the kernel is isomorphic to:

$\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

That if beacuse of each $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ there are three elements in the kernel $(a,-a),(a,3-a),(a,6-a)$.